# how can I get users to log in correctly on rails 3? instead of just getting redirected to the visitor front page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using omniauth to allows users to sign up/sign in. I'm trying to add this on top of a simple authentication log in/log out system that I already have in place. I am not using Devise. How can I have a user who logs in with omniauth have the same status as currently defined :signed_in_user?

I have most of the code set up except I'm trying to figure out how to get the user to actually log in and show their logged in page when doing it with omniauth.

First here's the omniauth authentications_controller which seems to work so far

```
def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
     flash[:success] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
  elsif current_user
   token = omniauth['credentials'].token
   secret = omniauth['credentials'].secret
   current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => token, :secret => token_secret)
   flash[:success] = "Authentication successful"
   sign_in_and_redirect current_user
   else
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    if user.save!
    flash[:success] = "Account created"
     sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)
   else
    session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
    redirect_to '/signup'
   end
end
end
```

Here's the sessions_controller which is used by the first authentication system

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

This is my sessions_helper
    module SessionsHelper

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    current_user = user
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    #what should go here?#
  end
```

Users_controller

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

    def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
          sign_in @user
          flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end
```

With my current authentication system (not omniauth), a redirect to root_url makes the signed-in user go to 'static_pages#home'

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @post = current_user.posts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the `sign_in` helper functions to `ApplicationHelper` so that you can use them in places other than the `SessionsController`.

After that, it should be very simple.

```
def sign_in_and_redirect user
  sign_in user
  redirect_to root_url  # or wherever you want
end
```

It might even be easier to just do `sign_in user and redirect_to root_url` instead of using another helper.

Comment: based on my code above, do you know why my token expires? After getting logged in, I came across this error `Invalid or expired token` under `Twitter::Error::Unauthorized in PostsController#create`

Comment: I'm not sure; I would recommend opening that as a new question.